# How to read several xlsx-files in a folder into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder. In this folder are 48 xlsx files, but the count of the relevant files are 22. Them name of these 22 files have no structure, the only thing in common is that the filenames start with data. I would love to access this files and read them all into a dataframe. Doing this manually with the code line

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')
```

takes too long

The table structure is similar but not always exactly the same. How can I manage to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

dfs = {}

def get_files(extension, location):
    xlsx_list = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
        for t in files:
            if t.endswith(extension):   
                xlsx_list.append(t)
    return xlsx_list

file_list = get_files('.xlsx', '.')
index = 0
for filename in file_list:
    index += 1
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    dfs[filename] = df

print(dfs)
```

each element in `dfs` like `dfs['file_name_here.xlsx']` accesses the data frame output from the `read_excel`.

EDIT: that you can add additional criteria to filter through the XLSX files at the line `if t.endswith(extension):` you can check out the beginning of the file like `if t.startswith('data'):` too. Maybe combine them `if t.startswith('data') and t.endswith(extension):`

Comment: Ty, may I ask you why u assigned location to '.' ? And how can I concatenate the dfs? Manually it's easy like df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) but the names of the files are quite long. Is there a possibility to do this in a for loop or something similar?